# Rails Date compared to Date.today

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, conditional-statements

I have a birth_date variable in the Date format. I want to compare it to Date.today as shown below. The problem is it is coming back false because it wants to compare the year as well. It is a birthday so I don't care about the year just trying to see if birth_date (month and day) is equal to Date.today.day.month.

Any ideas?

```
bdays = Soldier.find(:all, :conditions => ["birth_date LIKE ?", Date.today] )
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will need to break up your date, because you want to ignore the year.  You will need to use some of the functions given by your SQL provider (the example below uses MySQL):

```
bdays = Soldier.find(:all, :conditions => ["DAY(birth_date) = ? AND MONTH(birth_date) = ?", Date.today.day, Date.today.month])
```

if you're using SQLite (rails' default database), it will be a bit more complicated because they don't have a real date type:

```
bdays = Soldier.find(:all, :conditions => ["STRFTIME('%d', birth_date) = ? AND STRFTIME('%m', birth_date) = ?", Date.today.day, Date.today.month])
```

Comment: Hi, This was a great help, thanks so much. One problem I am still having is for SQLite the STRFTIME('%m', birth_date) = ? will return the month of January as 01 and then Date.today.month as 1 causing a false. I have searched all over trying to find someone else with this issue.

Answer (score 4):

Figured I would add postgres:

`Soldier.where("EXTRACT(DAY FROM birth_date) = ? AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM birth_date) = ?", Date.today.day, Date.today.month)`