# Display if attribute is same as today's date

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I am working on an application where I want to display a video on the main page of the site. The video model has an actual_date and public_filename attribute. Now a user sets the actual date as :date in the model. I am trying to figure out how to best go about making the video on the homepage display the video that is assigned to today's date. My homepage view is:

Please wait while the video loads...

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var s1 = new SWFObject('/flash/player.swf','player','500','372','9');
s1.addParam('allowfullscreen','true');
s1.addParam('allowscriptaccess','always');
s1.addParam('flashvars','file=<%= current_video.public_filename %>');
s1.write('preview');
</script>
```

I just included the current_video method, as I was playing around with creating one to return to the view with the right video url.

So I need a way to look at all of the videos in the database, see if any of the actual_date attributes are equal to today's date and if so tell current_video that it equals that video.

Thank you for any input or suggestions you might have!

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052964/rails-date-compared-to-date-today

Comment: Thank you, that helped, I got 
@current_video = Video.find(:all, :conditions => ["actual_date LIKE ?", Date.today] )

But that returns an Array, which I cannot call public_filename on... how do I return only the one video that matches the date so I can call the attributes.

Comment: Calling `first` method on array will return the first element (in your case, Video) of it. I strongly suggest you read up on the methods provided by the `Enumerable` module, they are very useful.
Alternatively, you can replace `Video.find` with `Video.first` to select only the first video from DB.

Comment: Didnt see your comment until now. Thank you for your answer as well. I am new to RoR but I should have realized that, feel pretty silly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't specify what should happen if more than one video has an actual_date that is equal to today's date. However, to retrieve one video just do:

```
@current_video = Video.first(:conditions => ['actual_date LIKE ?', Date.today])
```

—or you can do:

```
@current_video = Video.last(:conditions => ['actual_date LIKE ?', Date.today])
```

Whether you use `first` or `last` will depend on if you have some secondary sort order set up on your `Video` model. If it were me I'd create a named scope for this:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :for_today, :conditions => { 'actual_date LIKE ?', Date.today }
end
```

—then you can do

```
@video = Video.for_today
```

Comment: Wow, cannot believe I didnt realize that, thank you so much. I have validations in place to ensure that only one video can go in one day. I learn something new every day :) Again thank you!